# Get post content with all filters applied, knowing post id

Tags: posts, filters

I've just started working with Wordpress and I need to get the content of a post with all filters applied (eg. the html content of the post as appears on the page after all the available filters have been applied).

I am using this:

```
$post = get_post($postid, OBJECT, 'display');
echo $post->post_content;
```

I am getting content like this, including some tags added in by the visual composer plugin:

```
...[vc_row][vc_column][vc_column_text]Lorem ipsum[/vc_column_text][/vc_column][/vc_row]...
```

Looks like this is the database value of that field and no filters are being applied.

Could anyone help me get the post_content (with all filters applied) of a post knowing the post id?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass that through the `the_content` filter like so:

`echo apply_filters( 'the_content', $post->post_content );`